# Why my double quotes are received as single quotes?

Tags: javascript, python, json, string

I create a JSON object in my Python and I send it to my JavaScript file to display the value on a website.

I already tried to use single quotes, single quotes between double quotes

```
InfosThymio = {"proxh": "N/A"}
```

Then I send it:

```
def getInfos():
    global infosThymio
    return str(infosThymio)
```

My problem is that the JavaScript get it like this:
`{'proxh':'N/A'}` and I get the `unexpected token ' at position 1`

In the JavaScript I use this way to get the JSON and to parse it:

```
 getRobotData() {
        api.get()
            .then((data) => data.json())
            .then((res) => {
                const data = JSON.parse(res);
                this.setCapteur('hProxi', data.proxh);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to write `const data = JSON.parse(res);` because the JSON is already parsed with the line `.then((data) => data.json())`

The line `.then((data) => data.json())` tells the computer to parse the JSON response from your API and return the resulting javascript object.

It would be more semantically correct to name your variables like this:

```
getRobotData() {
  api.get()
    .then((res) => res.json()) // The JSON response is parsed into data
    .then((data) => {
      // Do something with your data
```